# R barplot - display legend even if only one category

Tags: r, plot, legend-properties

I am plotting values from multiple data sets in the same plot under a stacked bars representation using the barplot() function in R and I have noticed that the legend is not displayed if for a certain plot I have data only from one data set. Having two or more categories (i.e., data sets) raises no problem and the legend is displayed correctly. Any idea if it is possible to force it to be displayed even for only one category ? Or I have to add a dummy category if for that plot I have data available from only one data set. Thank you.

EDIT : Here is how I call the bar plot:

```
barplot(bars, col = color_map[available_data], legend.text = T, 
        args.legend(bty = 'n'), ylim = my_computed_ylim, 
        xlim = my_computed_xlim, xlab = "X label", ylab = "Y label") 

a = rep(5,25) 
b = rep(10,25) 
bars = rbind(a,b) 
barplot(bars, col = seq(1,nrow(bars), by = 1), legend.text = T, 
        args.legend = c(bty = 'n')) bars = bars[-1,] barplot(bars, 
        col = 2, legend.text = T, args.legend = c(bty = 'n'))
```

Comment: For us to help you, you need to provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536). You can also fix this yourself by calling [?legend](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/legend.html).

Comment: have a look at the examples in ?barplot. Especially the one plotting VADeaths. If that doesn't help you, put some data up and the code you tried and we can help you. Also take a look at ?legend

Comment: @gung It is pretty difficult to give you example data as I am working on a virtual machine in a secured environment and I cannot copy/paste stuff.

Comment: I am now adding an example.. when my edit button becomes enabled : ]

Comment: OK. Edit button is still disabled. Here is some example:
    `a = rep(5,25)`
    `b = rep(10,25)`
    `bars = rbind(a,b)`
    `barplot(bars, col = seq(1,nrow(bars), by = 1), legend.text = T, args.legend = c(bty = 'n'))`
    `bars = bars[,-1]`
    `barplot(bars, col = 2, legend.text = T, args.legend = c(bty = 'n'))`

Comment: @gung Thanks for adding the code. Can you please change `bars = bars[,-1]` to `bars = bars[-1,]` ? I made a mistake. I still do not get why I am not allowed to edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An automatic coercion into a vector happened when you typed `bars = bars[-1,]`. For this to work, you should convert back to a matrix with named rows.

Example:

```
a = rep(5,25); 
b = rep(10,25); 
bars = rbind(a,b); 
barplot(bars, col = seq(1,nrow(bars), by = 1), legend.text = T, args.legend = c(bty = 'n')); 
bars = matrix(bars[-1,],nrow=1); rownames(bars)=c('b');  ### THIS IS DIFFERENT
barplot(bars, col = 2, legend.text = T, args.legend = c(bty = 'n'))
```

Does this help?

**edit:**

To really see the difference between the two beasts, look at this example:

```
> a = rep(5,25); b = rep(10,25); bars = rbind(a,b); 
> bars
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17]
a    5    5    5    5    5    5    5    5    5     5     5     5     5     5     5     5     5
b   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10
  [,18] [,19] [,20] [,21] [,22] [,23] [,24] [,25]
a     5     5     5     5     5     5     5     5
b    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10


> bars.old = bars[-1,]
> bars.old
 [1] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10


  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
> bars.new = matrix(bars[-1,],nrow=1); rownames(bars.new)=c('b');
> bars.new
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17]
b   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10
  [,18] [,19] [,20] [,21] [,22] [,23] [,24] [,25]
b    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10
```

Comment: Yeah, you are right. In my actual code I was coercing back to a matrix before plotting, but forgot about the dimension names. Thank you :] I was expecting an x or something by default though